# Why does medicine term total number of pregnancies carried over the threshold of viability 'parity'?

Tags: etymology, medical

[Gravidity and Parity Definitions (Implications in Risk Assessment) | Patient](https://patient.info/doctor/gravidity-and-parity-definitions-and-their-implications-in-risk-assessment)

> **Gravidity** is defined as the number of times that a woman has been pregnant.
>
> **Parity** is defined as the number of times that she has given birth to a fetus with a gestational age of 24 weeks or more, regardless of whether the child was born alive or was stillborn.
>
> For example, a woman who is described as 'gravida 2, para 2 (sometimes abbreviated to G2 P2) has had two pregnancies and two deliveries after 24 weeks, and a woman who is described as 'gravida 2, para 0' (G2 P0) has had two pregnancies, neither of which survived to a gestational age of 24 weeks.

How does the medical definition of parity relate to its [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=parity)?

> 1570s, "equality or equivalence of rank or status," from French *parité* (14c.) or directly from Late Latin *paritas* "equality," from Latin adjective *par* (genitive *paris*) "equal" (see [par](https://www.etymonline.com/word/par?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_7161) (n.)). Meaning "state or condition of being on a level" is from 1610s.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the following article it derives from Latin parere:

From [onlinelibrary.wiley.com](https://obgyn.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1471-0528.15135)

> The use of ‘parity’ in relation to childbirth only appeared in the fourth quarter of the nineteenth century and comes from the [Latin parere,](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/parere) ‘to give birth, bring forth’.

[Quotation](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/pario) from Vulgate, Isaiah 7:14:

> - ecce virgo concipiet, et pariet filium, et vocabitur nomen eius Emmanuel
>   (*behold, a virgin shall conceive, and bear a son, and shall call his name Immanuel.*)

(Wiktionary)

Comment: Yep - same root as "parent".